# Match only letter characters in a string REGEX

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to  cleanse some data from a file.
There is a "Name" column containing strings with names and some of them contain symbols lile "/" ,"@"  ,while others contain  dashes (-) or ".".  Dashes and dots  are allowed  and should be retained.

Example:Gustav Mag$nus  Oswald ,    Mr. Clement Fleevle  Fust-Kratz

Result:
         Gustav Magnus Oswald, 
         Mr. Clement Fleevle Fust-Kratz

So far I've come up with this:   `[^a-zA-Z ]+` but it it's not working.

I tried to match  3 words  -  `^[a-zA-Z0-9_  ]+( [a-zA-Z0-9_  ])+( [a-Za-Z0-9_  ]) *$`

What I am missing ?

Comment: Your result has non letter characters in it.

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49536225/edit) and include your matching /replacing code. Also you need to add a tag for which language you are using - Javascript, Perl, Java, C#, ... ?

Comment: This isn't the job for pure regex, but a regex replacement in a programming language might be viable.  Please respond to the above 2 comments.

Comment: If you're going to validate names, be very certain what you want to do with names that contain non-ASCII characters, like öèŏąф, etc. You'll never be able to catch them all with regex.

Comment: Are you looking for some sort of substition like this: [`[$\/@]`](https://regex101.com/r/aMciMD/3/)

Comment: @coladict or you could define a valid alphabet and do negative search

Comment: I would suggest you don't even validate names. It's a bad idea. There are so many possibilities and practically no benefit. In the US, Canada and UK, for example, a person can legally have a mononym instead of first and last name. I give those as examples since the format presented is likely a UK or UK-affiliated naming convention. Many foreign countries (not Western countries) also allow mononyms.

Comment: I am using java.

Comment: Also not everyone has three names. Some people have five, and some people have two. And some have just one, like Teller https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teller_(magician)

Answer (score 0):

What about writing code like this?

```
String name = "Gustav M@g$nus Oswald"; // this name comes from your data source
String cleansedName = name.replace("$", "s").replace("@", "a");
```

So, what should happen with Strings that contain non-replacable, not allowed characters?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
String name="Gustav Mag$nus Oswald , Mr. Clement Fleevle Fust-Kratz";
String newString = name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Zs+,-]{1,}"," ").replaceAll("\\s{1,}"," ");
System.out.println(newString);
```